# Twitter's new official Tweet Button : who's tested it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, twitter

I'm working on a website where a 'Tweet This' type button is essential (as is a facebook 'like').

About a week ago Twitter launched [their own official Tweet button](http://twitter.com/goodies/tweetbutton). I'm curious to hear anyone's experiences with using it, particularly in comparison to [TweetMeme](http://tweetmeme.com/) and [John Resig's ReTweet script](http://ejohn.org/blog/retweet/).

I'm interested in any performance issues, any general tips or things not to do when implementing a Tweet button.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the official Tweet button, since Twitter has control over it and updates would be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

For my site, the official button shows different value from TweetMeme